# What Swing text component can I use to have hyperlinks open in browser?

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink

I have a JEditorPane which has been set uneditable with JEditorPane#setEditable(false) that is set to display HTML that I load from an external source of which I have no control of. Many times there are hyperlinks in the HTML, however while hovering over the link will change the cursor to a interactive image (in widows, changing from pointer to finger), clicking the hyperlink will do nothing.
[image]

Is there any swing component I can use that will display text in this sort of manner, but will respond to clicking a hyperlink and open the default web browser?

Comment: *"I have an uneditable JTextEditor.."*  Never heard of it.  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  Note that this is fairly easy to do with a `JEditorPane` ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson it is an JEditorPane. I just had a brain-fart. Fixing it now. I'm just doing this as a hobby, so I have little to no experience with swing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detecting the click on the link is relatively easy, as described in the [`JEditorPane` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html).

Then use [`Desktop.browse(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse-java.net.URI-) to show the URL in the default browser.

Comment: Thank you, trying this now.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: Odd. It worked for a while but HyperlinkEvent#getUrl() is now consistently returning null.

Comment: *"Odd. It worked for a while but.."*  Time for a new question.  For best help, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Will do. I'll ask in the morning once I get some sleep. TGIF.